# Seeking answers of Magento certification question is on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I can see some questions which are asking in our site typically about Magento certification questions such as **[this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281025/confusion-in-m2-professional-certification-question-1)** and **[this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281023/confusion-in-m2-certification-question)**.

Is this an on-topic?

In my opinion, if this question is actually from the Magento certification exam, then it should be closed as off-topic as it destroys the credibility of the exam. If this question is a model question, then it should be on-topic as we can see the questioner asking for reasoning.

So I am a little bit confused. What is your thought on this?

Comment: Summoning @benmarks on this.

Comment: Rajeev, i agree with your points but Ben Mark is the best person for this question.

Answer (score 4):

Posting exam questions and their possible answers would be a violation of the terms that are agreed to before a test is taken.

Questions like that should not only be closed but should *also be deleted* by a moderator.

Conversely, if the StackExchange question simply asks about the general topic covered in the exam question, there is no problem. Also, if the question is provided as one of the sample questions in Magento's study guide, it would be less problematic, but still a violation of copyright.

Comment: I think when we start certification exam at that time we agree some terms and condition, in that also it is mentioned that we can not disclose exam questions as it is

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, if those are real test questions, they would have been posted completely disregarding that agreement.